# MongoDB: Remove attribute from nested Object Array

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array

I have to remove an attribute from an deep nested object inside an array of objects.
It looks like this: 
[image: Array]

I want to unset the **IndividualAge** only for one specific **Period** Type *Past*
for one specific **Block** with  the name "**HouseKeepingDamageCost**", if it **exists**.
 I have to take care, because the other Objects inside **Blocks** and 
 other **Periods** have also an attribute called "**IndividualAge**", they can stay. 
Can someone help me ? I tried it with $elemMatch without success.

Thanks in advance.

Playgorund with my Data & Query: [Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UBTHhjZpB98)

Comment: add sample data and also the query you tried https://mongoplayground.net/ and update the story with the link.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar I did add the data & my attempt, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [arrayfilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#specify-arrayfilters-for-an-array-update-operations) to do so:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$unset": {
    "Blocks.$[block].Periods.$[period].IndividualAge": ""
  }
},
{
  "multi": false,
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "block.Name": "HouseKeepingDamageCost"
    },
    {
      "period.Type": "Past"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v6TeVH-0eB2)

Comment: this doesn't work for my provided data.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/-Apag7fTtN-

Comment: `HousekeepingDamageCost` is not with a captial `K` in the data in your link. regardless if it works for my toy example just adapt it to your code and make sure the values match what you intend.